# CMS + система контроля версий

Tags: svn, wordpress, git, cms, php

Никак не могу решить, стоит ли "контролировать" сайт который планируется создавать на wordpress или просто развернуть на хостинге без всяких  git'ов и работать с ним напрямую через браузер или ftp при необходимости.
Дело в том, что ранее я использовал svn/git только когда создавал проекты на голом php или с использованием фреймворков и когда работало по 3 человека одновременно.
Сейчас нужно сделать обычный сайт на wordpress. Подскажите пожалуйста, у кого опыта и знаний побольше, "совмещают" ли вообще cms и vcs?

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему "сайт на wordpress" выделяется в отдельную категорию. Контроль версий полезен вообще для всего, что делается. Или есть какие-то соображения, которые в вопросе не указаны? Да и то сомневаюсь, что они будут оправданием для неиспользования VCS :)

Comment: Почему бы не отслеживать историю и WordPress?  

    git commit -m "WP-markdown updated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сайты на популярных CMS частенько ломают через известные уязвимости, и полезно иметь возможность легко найти изменённые файлы, накатить последнюю версию из мастера и так далее. Весомый аргумент «за».

Но есть тонкости: если просто совместить локальный репозиторий и documentroot веб-сервера то придётся дополнительно защищать служебные файлы git-а. Как по мне лучше продумать механизм деплоя сайта из git-а.

Так-же стоит помнить что у WP есть собственные механизмы обновления (сейчас минорные обновления самого WP ставятся вообще автоматически, в планах автоматически обновлять вообще всё). Это не очень хорошо вяжется с vcs. Наверное можно что-то придумать, но хороших вариантов с ходу в голову не приходит.

Сам я давно подумываю об использовании git для контроля wp (и вообще наведении порядка в работе над сайтом), но пока-что использую просто ежедневные бекапы и всяческие скрипты проверяющие неизменность файлов. Если придумаете как совместить git и wp так что-бы сохранить плюсы обеих систем — напишите. Может-даже «исследование» тут.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Успокоили. @MrClon для деплоя на ftp использую эту штуку: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp Иногда глючит, но надеюсь последняя версия работает стабильно.

Comment: @dmitmedv, успокоил? Я вроде наоборот запугиваю (:

Comment: @MrClon просто были мысли, что cms и vcs совмещаются очень редко и в особых случаях, оказалось, что это обычное дело, что я и хотел выяснить =))